# What's the difference between "Build and Go (Run)" and "Build and Run" in XCode?

Tags: xcode

What's the difference between "Build and Go (Run)" and "Build and Run" in XCode? Why is this so Ambiguous?

Answer (score 2):

Build and Run will always Run.
Build and Go will load the debugger, if relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you just click "Build and Go" it's the same as "Build and Run"... any modified files are compiled and linked then your application is executed.

But if you click-and-hold on the "Build and Go" icon then after a second or so you should see a pop-up appear that presenets the choices "Build and Run", "Build and Debug", "Run Executable" or "Debug Executable". (Not the best use of UI IMO :) )